Replication lag b/w remote data centers
I am facing replication lag in postgres16 at times, and not able to find the reason.
Please find the configuration:

Two replication slots for two servers (one is on the same data center, another remote)
weekly once/twice facing lag (around 2GB for 1k TPS environment) in the remote replication slot and another same data center server slot with 0 lag.

My observation:

Noticed pg_stat_replication_slot total_txn reduced from 1000 to around 10 TPS but other
slot withing same data center is same with 1k TPS

noticed lag for remote slot but fine with same data center

Most importantly I have plenty of Bandwidth available in n/w ,2GB is still freely available out of 4GB network.

No IO issues on servers;


Trying to understand the reason for delay?
How the logical decoding total_txn is counting the view pg_stat_replication_slot does it stops decoding if any lag?

This is usually caused by replication conflicts.

This is logical replication @LaurenzAlbe,Do you think these are due to conflicts? I am not able to fallow you, what causes logical replication delay.Can you please let me know,why pg_stat_replication_slot almost stopped total_txn decoding count ?

You didn't mention that, which highlights how much detail is lacking in your question.
